# Get network edges from SQL tables for networkX in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, networkx

I am trying to get the number of network edges from a normalised SQLite database which has been normalised as follows:

```
 Authors                    Paper                      Paper_Authors
 | authorID | name | etc    | paperID | title | etc    | paperID  | authorID |
 |    1     | .... | ...    |    1    | ..... | ...    |    1     |    1     |
 |    2     | .... | ...    |    2    | ..... | ...    |    1     |    2     |
 |    3     | .... | ...    |    .    | ..... | ...    |    1     |    3     | 
 |    4     | .... | ...    |  60,000 | ..... | ...    |    2     |    1     |
 |    5     | .... | ...                               |    2     |    4     |
 |    .     | .... | ...                               |    2     |    5     |
 | 120,000  | .... | ...                               |    .     |    .     |
                                                       |  60,000  | 120,000  |
```

With somewhere in the region of 120,000 authors and 60,000 papers, and the index table has around 250,000 rows.

I am trying to get this into networkX to do some connectivity analysis, inputting the nodes is simple:

```
 conn = sqlite3.connect('../input/database.sqlite')
 c = conn.cursor()
 g = nx.Graph()
 c.execute('SELECT authorID FROM Authors;')
 authors = c.fetchall()
 g.add_nodes_from(authors)
```

The problem I am having arises from trying to determine the edges to feed to networkX, which requires the values in a tuple of the two nodes to connect, using the data above as an example;

```
 [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,4),(1,5),(4,5)]
```

Would describe the dataset above.

I have the following code, which works, but is inelegant:

```
 def coauthors(pID):
     c.execute('SELECT authorID \
                FROM Paper_Authors \
                WHERE paperID IS ?;', (pID,))
     out = c.fetchall()
     g.add_edges_from(itertools.product(out, out))

 c.execute('SELECT COUNT() FROM Papers;')
 papers = c.fetchall()

 for i in range(1, papers[0][0]+1):
     if i % 1000 == 0:
         print('On record:', str(i))
     coauthors(i)
```

This works by looping through each of the papers in the database, returning a list of authors and iteratively making list of author combination tuples and adding them to the network in a piecemeal way, which works, but took 30 - 45 minutes:

```
 print(nx.info(g))
 Name: 
 Type: Graph
 Number of nodes: 120670
 Number of edges: 697389
 Average degree:  11.5586
```

So my question is, is there a more elegant way to come to the same result, ideally with the paperID as the edge label, to make it easier to navigate the the network outside of networkX.

Comment: Isn't the network defined directly by the rows in `Paper_Authors`? How is the tuple list you show related to the example data?

Comment: @CL. unfortunately not, as networkx seems to require the tuple that defines the edge to be in the format `edge = (node,  node)`, so in this case `paper = (author, author)`, using the `Paper_Authors` data would be in the format `edge = (author, paper)` unless there is a way to define 2 kinds of nodes and then collapse the network somehow.

Comment: @CL. Investigated this a little more, and it does work, if I give the authors and papers a different prefix and essentially have two different kind of nodes, one for papers and one for authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all combinations of authors for each paper with a self join:

```sql
SELECT paperID,
       a1.authorID AS author1,
       a2.authorID AS author2
FROM Paper_Authors AS a1
JOIN Paper_Authors AS a2 USING (paperID)
WHERE a1.authorID < a2.authorID;         -- prevent duplicate edges
```

This will be horribly inefficient unless you have an index on `paperID`, or better, a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) on both `paperID` and `authorID`, or better, a [WITHOUT ROWID table](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly and only took around 2 seconds on around 600,000 output rows, I'll have a look at the other speedups too. Thanks a lot for the answer, the problem I was having with my thinking was how can I select the authorID, when I'm already selecting the authorID.